# Is it possible to set a border for ListTile? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, styling

How to set a border for **ListTile** widget? Here is no property "decoration" for it in docs. So I can't apply border for this element as usual. I also can't wrap ListTile's properties like *title, subtitle, leading, trailing* in Container because it doesn't work. However it could be really strange if here is no any cunning way to style ListTile with a border...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

ListTile has "shape" property. To add border you can simply add this line of code. There is no need to wrap it in card or container.

```
 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
```

Happy coding...

Answer (score 15):

```
const ListTile(
    leading: Icon(
        Icons.question_answer_outlined,
        color: Colors.blue,
        size: 25,
    ),
    title: Text('TEXTO'),
    trailing: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
        color: Colors.black26,
        size: 15,
    ),
    shape: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 6):

Try below code.

```dart
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    side: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.green.shade300,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)
  ),
  child: ListTile(
    leading: Text('Name'),
    title: Text('Username')
  )
)
```

Comment: Flutter offers a lot of ways to style a `ListTile`, but I recommend just wrapping with a `Container` (or with a `Card`)